# How to create custom dockerfile using nexus-blobstore-google-cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, nexus3

Can anyone please share `Docker` file or repository that creates an image on which Cloud Storage plugin is already installed? Nexus plugin to write data into Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

you can pull the images using docker

```
docker pull gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
```

check this [github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker) to find more information

Comment: actually i want to make a contanier on which nexus along with this plugin "https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-blobstore-google-cloud" is installed

Comment: hey @AsadUllahKhan, if you check the github repo, there is an already existed [Dockerfile](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-blobstore-google-cloud/blob/master/Dockerfile). use it directly as it already contains the requested libraries.